# Add Github Library To Android Project

Tags: java, android, github

I'm trying to add the following into my project:

https://github.com/florent37/AwesomeBar

I'm not exactly sure how to do this after reading the readme on the github. I tried adding:

```
compile 'com.github.florent37:awesomebar:1.0.3'
```

Into the dependancies of my gradle file but this caused an error.

And then how do I actually use this action bar? Do I just create a new .xml file with the code in the readme? Then the java code into a class?

Comment: "but this caused an error". Great. What is the error?

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Use `implementation` instead of `compile`:

```
implementation 'com.github.florent37:awesomebar:1.0.3'
```

And make sure you have:

```
jcenter()
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

In your root `build.gradle` repositories.

> And then how do I actually use this action bar? Do I just create a new
>   .xml file with the code in the readme? Then the java code into a
>   class?

[Library usage](https://github.com/florent37/AwesomeBar#usage)

Answer (score 0):

Check your import in layout xml. It should be -

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```